# Angular2 - Declaring a component in two different modules

Tags: angular

I create **DynamicForm** component connect it in two NgModule.

```js
//  Module 1
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [
        DynamicForm
    ],
    providers: []
})

//  Module 2
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [
        DynamicForm
    ],
    providers: []
})
```

But project dont work, any errors. When I remove **DynamicForm** from one of NgModule get error that I need include this component. Also I tryed connect **DynamicForm** to *app.module* and remove from NgModule and also did't work.

What to do?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you show your app.module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Components can only be part of *one* module. For this reason, if you have a component that should be used by multiple modules, create a shared module, declare it there, then export so others can use it. Then import that shared module into the module where you need that component

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DynamicForm
  ],
  exports: [
    DynamicForm
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule ]
})
class ModuleThatNeedsDynamicForm {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on user: @peeskillet answer

Two ways of declaring a component in two different modules:

1. As suggested in the @peeskillet answer, create a shared module and declare your component (and any other shared components) there and then import the shared module in the another module where you want to use the shared component as a dependency.
2. Create a separate module for the dependent component itself, and import the component module in the another module where you want to use the shared component as a dependency. The advantage of doing this is that you just importing what you want and not the other components from the shared modules.

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
> import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     CommonModule
>   ],
>   exports: [MyComponent],
>   declarations: [MyComponent]
> })
> export class MyComponentModule { }
> ```